# Вывести команду в консоль из Qt5 C++

Tags: c++, консоль, qt5, ubuntusdk

Посмотрел разные варианты работы с консолью, но так и не нашёл подходящего. Необходимо вывести в консоль команду на исполнение так, как если бы я сам её там вводил. Дело в том что большинство программ у меня получается запускать только с одним параметром используя QProcess. Будьте добры покажите рабочий вариант данного решения.

```
   process.start("mutt", QStringList << "param");
    if( !process.waitForStarted() || !process.waitForFinished() ) {
        return;
    }
```

Более развёрнуто:

```
void transport_mail ()
{
        QString buf;
        QProcess process;
        buf = "mutt -s "; buf += '"'; buf += "tema1";
        buf +='"'; buf += " mail@gmail.com";
        buf += " < /home/alexandr/1.txt";
        qDebug () << buf; 

        process.start(buf);
        if( !process.waitForStarted() || !process.waitForFinished() ) {
            return;
        }

        qDebug() << process.readAllStandardError();
        qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();

}
```

Выводит в консоли:

```
"mutt -s "tema1" mail@gmail.com < /home/alexandr/1.txt"
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("mutt") is still running.
```

Но если к там один параметр, то всё ок. Если в консоли самому ввести, то тоже всё работает.
UbuntuSDK - Qt5, C++

Comment: верно, это я сейчас по памяти встраивал, результат тот же

Comment: Напишите простую программу, которая будет выводить полностью свою командную строку и пробуйте экспериментировать с ней. Иначе можно будет долго гадать что именно передается и как.

Comment: Команда есть mutt -s "tema" mail@gmail.com < /home/user/1.txt как её через QT отправить чтобы работала?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QProcess` действительно не умеет работать с командами, использующими перенаправление ввода-вывода. Зато предоставляет функции, позволяющие их эмулировать.

```
QString command("mutt");
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-s"
          << "\"tema1\""
          << "mail@gmail.com";

QProcess process;
process.setStandardInputFile("/home/alexandr/1.txt"); // Изменить стандартный ввод
process.start(command, arguments);
```

Другие полезные методы:

```
process.setStandardOutputFile("output.txt"); // Изменить стандартный вывод
process.setStandardErrorFile("errors.txt");  // Изменить вывод ошибок

// или даже так:
QProcess process2;
process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2); // аналог конвейера command1 | command2 

process1.start(command1);
process2.start(command2);
```

Comment: Благодарю за пример.

Answer (score 2):

QProcess почему-то не хочет работать с перенаправлением ввода >> << > <, когда те передаются в качестве аргументов в QStringList. Возможно, эту проблему можно решить, почитав документацию.

А пока предлагаю вот такой костыль с созданием временного файла на диске.

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //создаём файл, вотором будет лежать bash-скрипт
  QFile tmp_file("run_command.sh");
  tmp_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
  //наполняем bash-скрипт содержимым
  tmp_file.write("#!/bin/bash\n");
  tmp_file.write("mutt -s \"tema1\" mail@gmail.com < /home/alexandr/1.txt"); //строка "netstat -atunp4 > netstat.txt" работала, по идее и Ваша команда должна выполниться 
  //устанавливаем права на чтение и исполнение
  tmp_file.setPermissions(QFile::ExeGroup | QFile::ExeOther | QFile::ExeOther | QFile::ExeUser | QFile::ReadOwner | QFile::ReadUser | QFile::ReadGroup | QFile::ReadOther);
  tmp_file.close();

  //запускаем наш скрипт
  QProcess proc;
  proc.start("./run_command.sh");
  proc.waitForFinished();

  //удаляем временный файл
  QFile::remove("run_command.sh");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хороший пример, не проверял, но костыль универсальный. Спасибо.

Comment: Проверил. Работает.

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```
QProcess pingProcess;
QString exe = "ping ya.ru";
pingProcess.start(exe);
pingProcess.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << pingProcess.readAllStandardOutput();
pingProcess.close();
```

Консоль:

```
"
Pinging ya.ru [213.180.193.3] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 213.180.193.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
"
```

Больше параметров и интереснее:

```
QProcess process;
QString exe = "python -c \"for i in range(10): print('*' * i)\"";
process.start(exe);
process.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
process.close();
```

Консоль:

```
"
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
"
```

Comment: поправил вопрос.

Comment: Я уже показал работающие варианты, осталось вам подогнать у себя. Доступа к вашей машине у меня нет, поэтому не смогу потестировать у вас. Попробуйте логировать `process.waitForStarted()` и `process.waitForFinished()`, а чтобы не было той ошибки "QProcess: Destroyed while ..." вызывайте `close()` перед выходом из функции. У меня подозрения что `process.waitForStarted()` вернул `false`, которое инвертировалось в `true`, и `process.waitForFinished()` не вызывался, т.к. на результат условия оно не повлияло бы

Comment: Подставил в первый вариант свою строку, результат не сильно поменялся. Теперь не выводит сообщение об ошибке, но команда всё равно не выполняется.

Comment: А просто при запуске `"mutt -s "tema1" mail@gmail.com < /home/alexandr/1.txt"` в терминале работает?

Comment: В терминале работает. process.waitForStarted() - true process.waitForFinished() - false

Comment: Есть вариант, который уже был в комментариях к вопросу. Напишите программу-заглушку, которая только принимает параметры и выводит их, после закрывается и подставьте ее вместо `mutt`

Comment: Честно говоря не очень понятно, как это реализовать. Я планировал получить какой нибудь простой и понятный способ отправления команд на выполнение, но видимо QProcess как то по особому обрабатывает команды. Может быть естть какой нибудь аналог echo для с++?